# Backing up ESXi VM to an external (USB) disk

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi, hard-drive

Does anyone know of a method to reliably back up ESXi 5 VM's (no vCenter) to an external USB disk (or a USB disk on another server)? If so, please share!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, in ovf export (File -> Export). not sure if it is a good idea to save to usb directly, as usb i/o is often iffy. it is better to save to your hd and then copy. done many many times with no issues.

Comment: But you cannot do this while the VM is powered-on, right?

Comment: ah yes, you would have to take a snapshot, write will then continue in incremental disks. you can then copy the main disk to create another vm and export that one. i think there are tools you can find such as ghettoVCB.sh that you can find on the net to make thing easier. i have not looked at these for a long time so cannot vouch for them, but the idea should work in general.

Comment: I'll definitely give ghettoVCB.sh a try - love the name!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.trilead.com/Features/

Comment: Accepting this answer because of @joeqwerty suggestion of Trilead, not the ovf export.